# Alterar Class de acordo com ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, classes

Tenho a seguinte estrutura.

```
<div id="cabecalho">
 <span data-bind="attr: { id: solicitacao.numero}"></span>
<div>
```

onde, solicitação me retorna um numero de 1 a 10
eu gostaria de adicionar uma class de acordo com o numero.

***Exemplo:***

```
if( span == 1 )
{
  $("cabecalho").children.addClass( "teste1" );
}
```

Comment: Uma pergunta. Por que você não faz direto? No atributo class coloca o valor direto ao invés da fazer depois via JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função data do jQuery para pegar a o valor do data-bind e verifique com o numero, assim:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .class1{background:red}
    .class2{background:blue}

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <span data-bind="1" class="">Oi</span>
      <span data-bind="2" class="">Olá</span>


         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>                                        
              $(document).ready(function(e) {
                  $('span').each(function(index, el) {
                      if($(this).data('bind') === 1){
                          $(this).addClass('class1');
                      }else{
                          $(this).addClass('class2');
                      }
                  });

              });
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```